# GNOME 43 listed as an update in GNOME Software on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I can see GNOME 43 update listed in "GNOME Software" but not in the built-in "Ubuntu Software" on my machine. Is it safe / supported to update it on 22.04?

[image: GNOME 43 update offered in GNOME Software on 22.04]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a backend update for some snap/flatpak app. This is not going to alter your GNOME 42 inteface in Ubuntu 22.04. It is safe to update it.